# Do you have to update Battlefield to play Revolution?

Tags: ps4, battlefield-1

I just bought the Battlefield 1 Revolution game and I have installed the add-ons on my PS4, but it keeps telling me to update the game to play online. Do I have to update the game for it to show up in the base game?

Also, is it possible to download the update on my computer and install it on the console?

Comment: 1. If the system message says you have to, you probably have to. 2. How is your computer connected to the internet? Can't you use the same connection on the console? 3. Updates are (almost) always a good idea, so I would recommend installing them.

Answer (score 1):

Battlefield 1 Revolution is not a new game or DLC, it was simply a bundle of sorts.

You most certainly do need to be fully up to date in order to play online (everyone needs to be on the same version after all, or things get weird). You usually cannot download updates to your PC and then plug them into you console either. Battlefield 1 does not have this, but perhaps if you contacted support they may be able to provide something? but don't expect it to succeed.

You should generally always keep your games (and add-ons, if applicable) up to date as they contain fixes, changes, and even new features.